# Any way to disable SSLv2 backwards compatibility mode for Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to connect to an HTTPs URL with Apache HttpClient 4.1....

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://federation/galaxy-class/enterprise/getSheildFrequencies");
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

During the connection process, I get the below exception...

```
Caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

When I turn on debugging, I see the below..

```
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
 main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110
 main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

So it seems like my client did the handshake in TLSv1 but then sent a client hello in SSLv2 which the server didn't like (it dropped the connection because it doesn't support SSLv2 backwards compatibility mode).

Is there any way to tell Apache HttpClient not to do that? Or is this something configured at the underlying JRE (I am using 1.6)?

**UPDATE**

As bmargulies suggested, I tried to make my own socket factory and configure it to only allow the protocols I want....

```
def supportedProtocols = new String[2]
supportedProtocols[0] = 'SSLv3'
supportedProtocols[1] = 'TLSv1'

 SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    SSLContext.getDefault(),supportedProtocols,
    null,
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

  Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
    .register("https", socketFactory)
    .build();

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
```

But this gives another exception...

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to connect.

Comment: Doc: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the current version of the http components
2. Use the [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#HttpClientBuilder())
3. Make your own socket factory and configure it to only allow the protocols you want.

---

```
 Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
    .register("http", PlainSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
    .register("https", new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext, hostnameVerifier))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SSLv2ClientHello` from the SSLContext's enabled protocols.

Comment: if you could share a code example, I would greatly appreciate it.